# Using type array for "batch"-calling of the same generic method with different generic parameters

Tags: c#, generics

I'm looking for some sleeker solution concerning the following: In a message bus implementation of mine I have several components which are subscribed to the event when new messages are published to the bus. The message bus transports BusMessage-objects (whose value is of `object`). Each component additionally implements a function to handle specific bus messages (derived components can override existing handle functions for certain message types) as follows e.g. for incoming string-typed bus messages:

```
protected virtual void HandleMessage(BusMessage<string> msg) { ... }
```

In order to distribute the incoming messages to the specific handle functions I have implemented an

```
static bool TryClassify<T>(BusMessage msg, Action<BusMessage<T>> handleFunction)
```

method which takes a T and checks for a given BusMessage whether it is actually a `BusMessage<T>` meaning that its value is of type T. The event handler is always as follows:

```
void HandleMessage(BusMessage msg)
{
  if (BusMessage.TryClassify<string>(msg, HandleMessage)) return;
}
```

With every specific BusMessage-type I want to handle in a component I must repeat that one line with TryClassify over an over again - the only difference is the type I specify, because the specific HandleMessage to be used is determined by the compiler. I end up with a method body consisting of

```
if (BusMessage.TryClassify<string>(msg, HandleMessage)) return;
if (BusMessage.TryClassify<bool>(msg, HandleMessage)) return;
if (BusMessage.TryClassify<long>(msg, HandleMessage)) return;
if (BusMessage.TryClassify<int>(msg, HandleMessage)) return;
if (BusMessage.TryClassify<DateTime>(msg, HandleMessage)) return;
...
```

Is there a more elegant, sleeker way with less boilerplate code to accomplish what I need? Something into the direction of using an array of types `{ typeof(string), typeof(bool), typeof(long), typeof(int), typeof(DateTime) }` maybe?

Comment: I assume you want to avoid using dynamic typing? How many places do you currently have this duplication? If it's just in a single method, I'd probably keep it as it is.

Comment: After understanding and reviewing Illidans4's solution to the problem, I agree with you and keep my code as it is - it will be easier to maintain in the future even though there are at least two dozens of places being cluttered up with the almost identical stack of lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build this code using expressions:

```
class BusMessage
{
    private static readonly Func<BusMessage,Delegate,bool> TryClass;

    static BusMessage()
    {
        Type[] classTypes = new Type[]{typeof(int), typeof(string)};

        MethodInfo mi = typeof(BusMessage).GetMethod("TryClassifyInternal", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

        var p1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(BusMessage));
        var p2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Delegate));
        Expression exp = null;
        foreach(Type t in classTypes)
        {
            MethodInfo mig = mi.MakeGenericMethod(t);
            Expression e = Expression.Call(mig, p1, Expression.Convert(p2, typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(BusMessage<>).MakeGenericType(t))));
            if(exp == null)
            {
                exp = e;
            }else{
                exp = Expression.OrElse(exp, e);
            }
        }

        TryClass = Expression.Lambda<Func<BusMessage,Delegate,bool>>(exp, p1, p2).Compile();
    }

    private static bool TryClassifyInternal<T>(BusMessage msg, Action<BusMessage<T>> handleFunction)
    {
        //former TryClassify code
        return false;
    }

    public static bool TryClassify(BusMessage msg, Delegate handleFunction)
    {
        return TryClass(msg, handleFunction);
    }
}
```

But, in this case, I would prefer your original code for clearness (and it's probably the shortest possible if you don't want to change code of other methods).

Comment: An interesting approach to the problem, especially for me because I never had something to do with Expressions before. However I'm now convinced to stick with my original way - due to readability and better understandability.